# How to clear activity stack from service?

Tags: android, service, android-activity, stack

I want to cear the activity stack of my application after a certain time. I invoke a service with the alarm manager to delete some data. Is it possible to also clear the activity stack with the service?

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a design flaw to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can "properly" do that.. but you can put a Broadcast Receiver on the Activities you want to close.

Then send a broadcast which they receive and then "finish()" themselves.